# BibTex in journal template APS

Tags: bibtex, templates, revtex

I'm trying to get working bibliography in this APS journal template (https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aps).

Using commands for BibTex found online it's not working. 
For example:

```
\cite{comune:1}
```

Just before `\end{document}`:

```
\bibliography{bib}
```

And after `\begin{document}`:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

So in the same folder i put a file `bib.bib` that contains the entry:

```
@ONLINE {comune:1,
    author = "Comune di Manfredonia",
    title  = "Preferenze Consiglio comunale - Riepilogo generale per Lista",
    month  = "may",
    year   = "2015",
    url    = "http://www.comune.manfredonia.fg.it/attivitaservizi/elettorale/ele2015/index.htm"
}
```

But this way it just doesn't show anything. What is going on?? Thank you

**[UPDATE]** Compiling BibTex (F11) and then two time PDFLatex (F6) i had the bibliography. But why link is splitted over two columns?

[image]

Comment: do you have a `\bibliographystyle{}` commands?

Comment: Yes, just after \begin{document}. Added in the original question.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. It works for me (tested on sharelatex)

Comment: Can you link me you source code? I can't get it working on sharelatex too

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/572e050f62f029dd0f121b0f

Comment: Restricted, i can't access it. Click on Share, then make it public.

Comment: You are not using sharelatex, you have to run bibtex yourself. Hit `F11` (default) and then twice more pdflatex (F6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

In the following example, I load the `revtex4-1` document class, since that's also the document class loaded by the template file you've provided a link to.

Observe that I would encase the contents of the `author` and `title` fields in curly braces in order to (a) inform BibTeX that the author is a "corporate" author (rather than a person whose first name is "Comune", whose "von" component is "di", and whose surname is "Manfredonia") and (b) to prevent BibTeX from lower-casing the words in the title field. I would further like to recommend you issue the instruction `\raggedright` immediately before `\bibliography`.

The following code appears to compile fine under ShareLaTeX.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@misc{xyz,author="ABC",title="DEF",year=3001}
@ONLINE{comune:1,
    author = "{Comune di Manfredonia}",
    title  = "{Preferenze Consiglio comunale---Riepilogo generale per Lista}",
    month  = "Maggio",
    year   = "2015",
    url    = "http://www.comune.manfredonia.fg.it/attivitaservizi/elettorale/ele2015/index.htm"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ reprint,amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{comune:1}, 
\cite{xyz} % dummy entry

\raggedright  % <- recommended
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, compiling BibTex and then two times pdflatex now i'm getting the bibliography. But the link is splitted over two columns (see original question). How can i get it like your image?

Comment: @slash89mf - Do you have just 1 bib entry, or more than 1? (Note that my example code used 2 entries; the screenshot showed only a part of the page generated by the mini-document.)

Comment: Just one. Do i need at least two entries?

Comment: @slash89mf - If you change my example to have only one `\cite` instruction, the remaining bib entry will be split across two columns. How serious/bad is this, in the grand design of things?